# Nginx maintenance proxy url

Tags: nginx, proxypass

i have a question regarding nginx config.

- I have a main page i want to be on maintenance mode. e.g.) url: `mypage.com`
- I have and existing generic website that has maintenance display. e.g.) url: generic.com/maintenance.html
- I want to reuse maintenance page from my generic website to mypage.com

so my minimum nginx settings is like this.

```
server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  localhost;
    set $maintenance true;
    port_in_redirect off;

    location / {
        if ($maintenance = true) {
            return 503;
        }
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
    
    error_page   503 @503_error;
    
    location @503_error {
        if ($maintenance = true) {
          rewrite ^(.*)$ /maintenance.html permanent;   
          proxy_pass http://www.generic.com;
        }
    }
}
```

surely i miss something but i'm not sure what.
i did a redirection and it should be fine. but just want to know if this can be done like this.

Comment: You have 3 options - either (a) proxy_pass to the second website when the first is in maintenance mode or (b) return 301 redirect to the browser with the URL of the maintenance page or (c) if both sites live on the same server then you can use internal rewrite of the location (and eventually change the `root`) to point to the file in your local filesystem which is responsible for rendering the maintenance page.

Comment: Try: `rewrite ^(.*)$ /maintenance.html break;` then the request should be sent to the `proxy_pass`.

Comment: @RichardSmith i tried the `rewrite ^(.*)$ /maintenance.html break;` it worked on my local. in real server it gives me, mypage.com is currently unable to handle this request.